# Character encoding for music symbols in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to store the characters ♯ and ♭ in a mySQL database, but ♯ gets stored as **Aâ™¯** and ♭ as **Bâ™**

In the HTML, I have used `♯` and `&#9839;` and both render fine in the browser, but neither is being stored correctly.

I have tried UTF-8 and UTF-16 character sets for both the PHP page and for the field where the values are being stored and I get the same result.

I'm not very familiar with character sets, so maybe I should be using something other that UTF-8 or -16 or maybe I'm missing something else entirely?

Comment: If you have proper encoding in DB, and proper encoding on page then use `SET NAMES 'utf8'` as first query and it should solve problem.

Comment: I found my problem. It was a typo in my HTML: `<option vale='C&#9839;/D&#9837;'>C&#9839;/D&#9837;</option>` I misspelled "value" and it made a difference to have the value defined by the text inside the tags rather than from the value attribute.  Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use varbinary / binary.
If you have again the problem, check your DB charset, table charset, col charset, php script charset.
If you have the problem after, you can use base64_(en|de)code :)